# In the Transformers aligned continuity, what was The Thirteenth's real name?

Tags: transformers, optimus-prime

It was said that before The Thirteenth went into the Well of Allsparks, he had asked Alpha Trion to remove his name from The Covenant of Primus. Hence why he was called 'The thirteenth'.

What was his original name before Alpha Trion changed it to 'The thirteenth'?

Comment: Ironically, it was Theophilus Triskaidekaphobia.

Answer (score 0):

In the Aligned Continuity, the Thirteenth Prime is *Optimus Prime*. After the destruction of the rest of the Primes and the creation of the Transformers race, Optimus enters the Well of Allsparks to be "reborn" as Orion Pax, with no memory of his previous life.

It's not until Orion Pax receives the Matrix of Leadership that once again becomes Optimus.

Sourced from the Transformers wiki page for [Optimus Prime](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Optimus_Prime_(WFC)).

Comment: So his name was 'Optimus Prime' then? If Alpha Trion had removed the name 'Optimus Prime', then there should be no normal cybertronian that should have said that name. Yet, Halogen was the one to declare to Orion Pax 'from this moment forward, you are Optimus Prime.'

Comment: In the _Transfomers Prime_ episode "New Recruit" Smokescreen mentions that Alpha Trion persuaded Halogen to make Orion Pax the "new" Prime. Alpha Trion himself was secretly a Prime and therefore knew Optimus's real identity, so it's not a big stretch to assume he told Halogen to use that name.

Comment: It was said that Alpha Trion had told the High Council that Orion Pax was 'The Prime', as in he's the The Prime that will fight the upcoming war. It doesn't say that he ever told them that Orion Pax was one of the thirteenth.

Comment: Your comment appeared to be asking why Halogen chose to name him "Optimus Prime", which is what I answered. I agree there is nothing to suggest Alpha Trion also told him that Optimus was one of the original thirteen primes (although there is nothing to suggest he didn't either).

Comment: The Well of Allsparks has that room of monkeys typing out names of people; the special thing about Optimus is those monkeys managed to randomly choose his name twice.